# Jquery onsubmit Function Runs Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following code :

```
 $("#add-form").on("submit", function (e) {
            var isValid = $('#add-form').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid();
            if (isValid == null || !isValid) {
                $('#add-form').data('bootstrapValidator').validate();
                return false;
            }
            var number = 0;
            e.preventDefault();
            var DepartureDate = $("#DepartureDate").val();
            var ArrivalDate = $("#ArrivalDate").val();
            var ArrivalTime = $("#ArrivalTime").val();
            var DepartureTime = $("#DepartureTime").val();
            if (DepartureDate == ArrivalDate && DepartureTime == ArrivalTime)
            {
                 var msg = "Departure time and Arrival time cant have the same value in the same day "
                showSmallBoxMsg('@GetResource("Menu.ID.20")', msg,@((int)Common.Enums.AlertStatus.Failed));
                $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);

            }
            return false;

        })
```

simply if the arrival time equals the departure time on the same day the form should not submit and views a message as you can see in the photo,[https://ibb.co/1rBMP5h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EzgD.png)
but the problem is after the function executed and message shows, the function runs again and the message appears one more time [https://ibb.co/9ch6WZ5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D4cw.png),
why is that happening

Comment: Could you please provide Html Code part? I would like to check are you doing it via form or something else.

Comment: im using html helpers form
[code]using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Departure", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "add-form", @class = "", novalidate = "novalidate", autocomplete = "off", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Comment: In my case its calling only 1 time And showing message single time.

Comment: That's what should be happening but not in my case unfortunately.

Comment: is it possible for you to share whole code for this specific page ?